Schema enforcement on parquet file in PySpark
Situation
I have parquet file and it has many columns. I am reading the file in pyspark (aws glue), what i seeing is file has schema mismatched value, when it infer schema if column is inferred as time/timestamp but some  values have other datatypes like string, it throwing error at load option only
df = spark.read.parquet(parquet_file_path)

Even if data is same like timestamp only, it has some wrong dates so overall it's failing at loading only (if in case thinking of filtering data, i cant load only)
I have defined schema now for that table (parquet file) and enforced schema and i can able to load the data and filter it (especially wrong date values ) but i expect strict schema enforcement as, if data type of colum doesn't match with schema just drop it or cast it (its not happening now as)
df = spark.read.schema(schema).parquet(parquet_file_path)

When i load the file it fails as I have column units and defined schema for that is int but data has some double values like (23.7)
Can I cast it or drop it (i am saying while loading only its failing)
Error is like defined int but got double, expected int but got double
What can be done here as solutions to enforcement schema?

Use PERMISSIVE mode for loading with schema
By default, PySpark enforces strict schema when loading files, which can cause failures if the schema doesn't match. You can relax this behavior by enabling the permissive mode for reading the Parquet file. PySpark will cast or replace problematic rows with null values.
df = spark.read \
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .parquet(parquet_file_path)

